# What is the number of subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ which sum to a given number $k \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to compute the number of ways to sum the first $n$ unique positive integers to a number $k$. This is not a partition of $n$ since we can't repeat numbers.

Any hints on how I can derive a generating function for this?

I encountered this in trying to compute the variance of the sum of $k$ balls randomly drawn from an urn of $n$ balls (where each ball is labeled with a unique positive integer from $1...n$). Letting $S$ be the random variable which is this sum, computing the variance using the definition of expectation directly uses $P(S = k) = \frac{N_{n,k}}{{n\choose k}}$, where $N_{n,k}$ denotes the desired quantity above. I can compute the variance by writing $S$ as a sum of indicators and expanding the expression inside of the expectation, but I was wondering if there was a nice expression for the above quantity.

Thank you!

Comment: Now I know what you are asking.

Comment: @Laz Ok! Just a hint to point me in the right direction would be appreciated :)

Comment: I believe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421909/enumerating-the-number-of-subsets-of-size-i-that-sum-to-a-specific-value is asking the same thing, but I'm not sure how the asker came up with that GF.

Comment: You can try to use some kind of induction to construct a formula, using something like this. If you have a formula for any $k\leq m$, then any subset $S_{m+1}$ whose sum is $m+1$ can be partitioned into two subsets, the subset ${1}$ (if $1\in S_{m+1}$) and a subset $S_m$ whose sum is $m$. Of course, you have to garantee that $1\notin S_m$. If $1\notin S_{m+1}$, now you try with $2$, and so on ... In how many ways can you do that? I don't know if it'll work, but you can twist that idea as much as you want.

Comment: The answer to the question is the number of solutions for $$1\cdot x_1+2\cdot x_2+3\cdot x_3+...+n\cdot x_n =k$$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. It's [generating function](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html) is
$$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^n)$$
and the coefficient of $x^k$ is the answer. But this doesn't make the problem easier.

Comment: I'm still interested in the solution to the question as asked, but is there a way to compute the variance I described above without invoking this number?

Comment: You seem to have used $k$ in two different senses: the sum with maximum $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and the number of balls drawn with maximum $n$ if the draw is without replacement

Comment: I don't think there can be a nice closed formula here.  The initial values $N_{n,k}: 1 \leq k \leq n$ agree with the number of partitions of $k$ into distinct parts, that is, the values of the partition function $q(k)$, for which there is no known closed form.

Comment: That's what I suspected from working out some cases. It's not an easy problem at all ...

Comment: For the computation of variance, I *believe* that linearity of expectation allows us to consider the drawing of each ball as an event with probability $k/n$ (even though the events are clearly not independent) and compute $E(X) =  \frac{k}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{k(n+1)}{2}$ and $E(X^2) =  \frac{k}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{k}{n} i^2 = \frac{k(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, and then use $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2.$

Comment: As for the question asked in the title, I have no idea.

Comment: @ConnorHarris What about the cross-terms in $E(X^2)$? I think that should be $E(X^2) = \frac{k}{n}^2 \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j \neq i} ji) + \frac{k}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i$

Comment: let $a(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts, and let $l_n=(n-\frac{1}{24})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then $$ a(n)\sim \frac{e^\frac{\pi\cdot l_n}{\sqrt{3}}}{4\cdot 3^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot l_n^{3/2}}$$ This is from the asymptotics component of the formula section on this link: https://oeis.org/A000009. sorry for the repostings had errors in math jax and doesn't allow editing after 5 mins.

Comment: @quantus14 could you please provide some intuition for how that expression is derived?

Comment: @fireyoni09 you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer was written for a previous version of the question, which asked how to compute the variance.

---

The distribution is not needed to compute the variance. Let $X_i \in {1,2 \cdots n}$, for $i\in {1,2 \cdots k}$, be the result of the $i-$th extraction. CLearly $X_i$ are identically distributed, but not independent.

Let $S=\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$

We have $E[S]=k E[X_1] = k \frac{n+1}{2}$

And $E[S^2] = k E[X_1^2 ]+ k(k-1)E[X_1 X_2]$

For the last term you can use $E[X_1 X_2]=E[X_1E[X_2 \mid X_1]]$

Can you go on from here?

I got $$Var(n,k) = \frac{k\,\left( n+1\right) \,\left( n-k\right) }{12}$$

At least it sounds consistent : $Var(n,n)=0$,$Var(n,1)=Var(X_1)$  and $Var(n,k)\to k n^2/12 $ for $n\gg k$

---

Edit: here goes some detail.

$$E[X_1^2 ]=\frac{2{{n}^{2}}+3n+1}{6}$$

$$E[X_1 | X_2 =j] =\frac{1}{n-1}\left( -j + \sum_{i=1}^n i \right)=\frac{1}{2n-2}\left( n^2 +n -2j \right)$$

$$E[X_1 X_2 ] =\frac{1}{2n-2}\left( (n^2+n)E[X] -2 E[X^2] \right)=\frac{3{{n}^{2}}+5n+2}{12}$$

$$E[S^2] = \frac{k\,\left( n+1\right) \,\left( 3kn+n+2k\right) }{12}$$

$$\sigma_S^2(n,k)=E[S^2] -E[S]^2= \frac{k\,\left( n+1\right) \,\left( n-k\right) }{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the **number of subsets**, the answer to the question is the number of solutions for
$$1\cdot x_1+2\cdot x_2+3\cdot x_3+...+n\cdot x_n =k$$
where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. It's [generating function](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentgeneratingfunctions.html) is
$$P_n(x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^n)$$
and the coefficient of $x^k$ is the answer $N_{n,k}$ (more reading [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html)). It can be computed from 
$$N_{n,k}=\frac{P_n^{(k)}(0)}{k!} \tag{1}$$
or, given $P_n(x)=P_{n-1}(x)(1+x^n)$, using recurrence:
$$N_{n,k}=N_{n-1,k}+N_{n-1,k-n} \tag{2}$$
where $N_{n,0}=1$ and $N_{n,k}=0, k >\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. According to the [same article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html), this is NP-complete problem.